# Recent feature changes

Tags: discussion

In case you want to now about these, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) is a the thread at meta.SO

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these sorts of announcements, I'm just going to close it because it's not really something that can be answered, and this way it doesn't pollute our unanswered questions list.